# Android: execute methods and wait for results (for ChangeLog)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, methods, changelog

I created an app in which I use a SQLiteDatabase custom class, in order to manage SQLite database, obviously.

I created a "ChangeLog" class to check my schema's modifies.
For example:

- Version 1.0.0: "table01" has 3 columns with "NOT NULL" constraint
- Version 1.0.1: "table01" has 3 columns, without "NOT NULL" constraint

If an user install last version of my app, I invoke a method applyModifies() from my ChangeLog class in order to apply several modifies and **ALTER** "table01", for example. 
(*To do this, I rename the old table, I create the new one, I copy all records to new table, I drop my old table and, finally, I rename the new table with original name.*)

I would need to call several methods inside *applyModifies()* (*update0001()*, *update0002()*, etc.). 
If first method fails, next methods don't have to start.

```
//[... ChangeLog Class - Methods ...]
public void applyModifies() {
       int version = checkVersion(); //Take version release of my app
       try {
            boolean b0001 = update0001();
            boolean b0002 = update0002();
            boolean b0003 = update0003();
       } catch (Exception e) {
            //
       }
 }
public boolean update0001() {
    //Verify actual table's schema and apply modifies, if needed
    //I use DB transaction to execute queries in block and wait for a result
    return result;
}
```

Normally, I could do something like:

```
boolean b0001 = update0001();
if (b0001) {
    boolean b0002 = update0002();
} else {
    //Previous method fails
}
```

but it's not a good solution, overall because I need to add several changelog modifies to apply and I don't know how to implement it yet.

Comment: What do you mean with "fails"? Aren't you using exceptions?

Comment: Yes, inside update0001() I have some try/catch block and, if it catches exception (or if it's not possible to execute the transaction for some reason), method returns false

Comment: Why would you do that? Just remove the try/catch.

Comment: Ok, but if I remove try/catch, am I sure that all operations will be executed in the correct order? I mean, am I sure that database operations will be "synced" just like I inserted them in my code? Because every update000n() contains INSERT/DROP queries and I need to execute every block in order.. That's why I wanted to wait for a sort of "success" message from every update method

Comment: This is Java, not JavaScript.